# A value that is equal to its class

Tags: clojure

That is, an `x` such that `(= x (class x))` is `true`.

I can only think of `nil` and `java.lang.Class`. What else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else exists. `class` always returns an object of type `java.lang.Class`, or nil if the argument is nil. There are no other exceptions, and nothing can be equal to an instance of `java.lang.Class` unless it is itself an instance of `java.lang.Class`. And if it is an instance of `java.lang.Class`, we know what value will be returned from `class` for it.